# Save Scikit-learn RandomForestClassifier in Weka J48 format

Tags: scikit-learn

I'm looking to save a fitted RandomForestClassifier in the format specified [Page 27 - Figure 26 here.](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/dm00563460-lsm6dsox-machine-learning-core-stmicroelectronics.pdf) Alternatively, if such a thing does not exist, how can I extract the internals of the decision trees to build the J48 formatted file myself? DecisionTreeClassifier makes this available through `tree.export_text`, but RandomForestClassifier does not have a `tree_` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toward the last sentence of your question, `RandomForestClassifier` has its fitted trees accessible through the attribute `estimators_`; these are instances of `DecisionTreeClassifier`, so each of them has a `tree_` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [sklearn-weka-plugin](https://github.com/fracpete/sklearn-weka-plugin) ([examples](https://github.com/fracpete/sklearn-weka-plugin-examples)), and train Weka's [RandomForest](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/trees/RandomForest.html) on your data, then you can create that output by simply turning the model into a string using `str(...)`.

Of course, this will require a Java JDK installation to run.